# Meteor - Error when loading/refreshing page: Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, routes, meteor-blaze

As described above, I am getting an error and an empty page (but the layout including the navbar is there) is shown. This error always occurs, when I refresh the link via the browser or in case I access the link directly through the browser. Everything is fine, when I use my navigation bar to navigate through the templates. So, I can´t see any data after a real "load" of the page.

I am using Meteor Blaze on Windows.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Neither the picture, nor other data is shown.

I am not sure, if this is 100% the reason for that behavior, but always if this behavior occurs, I get this error message in the client console:

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined

and

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
>       at Blaze.TemplateInstance. (http://localhost:3000/app/client/templates/common/navigation.js?hash=142e989d312ba94a4b875a71e5e557bdd5255272:3:40)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3398:22
>       at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744:12)
>       at fireCallbacks (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3394:12)
>       at Blaze.View. (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3487:5)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1845:14
>       at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271:12)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1844:15
>       at Object.Tracker._runFlush (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:548:11)
>       at onGlobalMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=6d285d84547b3dad9717a7c89c664b61b45ea3d8:398:23)
>   undefined

I searched for tracker, afterFlush etc., but I am not sure what I have to change in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load this route "fresh" (using a refresh or pasting the url into the browser) Meteor reloads the entire application *including the `Meteor.user()` object*. At line 40 of `client/templates/common/navigation.js` you are probably trying to access `Meteor.user().username` but `Meteor.user()` hasn't yet loaded so you get the error. You need to defend against this in your code and/or show a loading template until your subscriptions and the user object are all ready.

The first line of the error dump points to the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined at Blaze.TemplateInstance.
(http://localhost:3000/app/client/templates/common/navigation.js?hash=142e989d312ba94a4b875a71e5e557bdd5255272:3:40)
```

The `:40` at the end there is the line number the error occurred on.

Comment: Perfect, solved! I just added a WaitOn function on every route, where the navbar is used (in consequence where `Meteor.user()` is needed). The function looks like: `Router.route('myRoute', {
 waitOn: function () {
  Session.set('me', Meteor.user().username);
  },   

  action: function () {
    this.render('myRouteTemplate');
}
});` . So , you were absolutely right, it was an issue about Meteor.user().username, which wasn´t already ready. Many thanks.